# Using Generic Type in class

Tags: swift, generics

I have class which keeps information about the unit of measure of a value. That class has to manage Double and Int numbers:

```
class TypedValue<T: Numeric> {    
    var value: T
    var unitOfMeasure: String?

    init(value: T, unitOfMeasure: String? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.unitOfMeasure = unitOfMeasure
    }

....
}
```

Then I have another class which performs some calculations (code below is just for sake of issue illustration):

```
class Container<T: Numeric> {
    var v: TypedValue<T>

    init(v: TypedValue<T>) {
        self.v = v
    }


    func f1() {
        switch v.value {

        case is Int:
            v.value = 2

        case is Double:
            v.value = 2.2 <--- Error Here!

        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'T'

I have also tried this:

```
 func f2() {
        v.value = TypedValue(2.2)
 }
```

and I get:

> Cannot assign value of type 'TypedValue' to type 'T'

How do I assign a new Double value to v (if v contains Double values)?

Comment: A generic type (like `T`) is always a **single** static type at runtime. It cannot be `Int` and `Double` at the same time. In this case cast the type `(v as! TypedValue<Double>).value == 2.2`

Answer (score 2):

You can add specific versions of the function in extensions:

```swift
extension Container where T == Int {
    func f1() {
        v.value = 2
    }
}

extension Container where T == Double {
    func f1() {
        v.value = 2.2
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that, if you create a container where the value is something other than Double or Int, you get a compiler warning when trying to call `f1()`.

That said, I would strongly recommend using Foundation's [`Measurement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement) type instead of rolling your own. It's very good.

If you insist on keeping your own type, deal with every value as a `Double` and deal with integers at a formatting stage for user-facing values.

Comment: Thank you for recommending Measurement, I was not aware of it. The extension is good if I call f1 from outside the class. If I call it from another method, I get an error: No exact matches in call to instance method 'f1'. Any thought about that.

Comment: Because inside the class, you just have T, so it doesn't know which of the extension methods to call. You will quickly tie yourself in knots with this, which is why I suggest measurement or just using Double everywhere.